# Instrument "driver" for labview in which the instrument is controlled over http

Tags: json, http, labview

So I have an instrument which can be talked to over HTTP GET and POST requests, this is so that the instrument can be controlled through a webpage. These requests include getting and setting variables and running functions on the instrument. The instrument returns json over http but this could be easily modified if need be. Does anyone have any idea where I would start making a driver?

Comment: Labview itself has flatten to/from json string functions and http client functions (including examples), should be sufficient. Plus there's a bunch of other labview json libraries out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [HTTP Client Library](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361K-01/lvcomm/http_client/)